# Extending a generic

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class Integrator {
    public abstract Point integrate();
    public abstract Point function(Double x, Point y);
}
```

which is extended by

```
public abstract class Euler extends Integrator {
    public Point integrate() {
        ... // this calls function(x, y)
    }
}

public abstract class Central extends Integrator {
    public Point integrate() {
        ... // this calls function(x, y)
    }
}
```

which both implement `integrate()` differently. Now, the concrete classes which I instantiate are defined like so

```
public class EulerIVP extends Euler {
    public EulerIVP(...) { ... }

    public Point function(Double x, Point y) {
        ...
    }
}

public class CentralIVP extends Central {
    public CentralIVP(...) { ... }

    public Point function(Double x, Point y) {
        ...
    }
}
```

which both implement `function()` exactly the same way, but will use their parent's `integrate()`. Because `Euler` and `Central` are `abstract` it doesn't make sense for them to both extend an `IVP` class. So I was hoping I'd be able to do something like this

```
public class IVP<T extends Integrator> extends T {
    public IVP(...) { ... }
    public Point function(Double x, Point y) { ... }
}

Integrator eulerIntegrator = new IVP<Euler>(...);
Integrator centralIntegrator = new IVP<Central>(...);
```

But I can't because, I believe, `T` here would be a type not a class. Is there something similar I can do?

Comment: If `function()` is the same for all, why not implement it in `Integrator` ?

Comment: It is only the same for this particular example. I could have another class which extends `Euler` but has a different `function`

Comment: I think you can use the [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use composition instead of inheritance. Something like:

```
public class IVP {
    private Integrator integrator;

    public IVP(Integrator integrator) {
        this.integrator = integrator;
    }

    public Point function(Double x, Point y) {
        // Calculate using integrator.integrate();
    }
}
```

and then make euler a non-abstract class:

```
IVP eulerIVP = new IVP(new Euler());
```

Comment: +1 I wanted to offer the same solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: But would this be possible if `integrate()` called `function(x,y)` of its child class? I've edited my question to make this clear.

Comment: @fophillips In that case, you could add a `setIVP` method to the integrator so that they can both refer to each other.

Comment: In the end I did it the other way around, and ensured all `Integrator`s were constructed with an `IVP`.